# Export file with ifstream and ofstream get percentage in c++

Tags: c++, file, export, ifstream, ofstream

I am exporting huge files concatenating four files to make a fifth (up to 100Mb) like this:

```
ifstream if_a("file1.txt", ios_base::binary);
ifstream if_b("file2.txt", ios_base::binary);
ifstream if_c("file3.txt", ios_base::binary);
ifstream if_d("file4.txt", ios_base::binary);
ofstream of_e("file5.txt", ios_base::binary);

of_e << "[FILE1]\n" << if_a.rdbuf();
of_e << "\n\n[FILE2]\n" << if_b.rdbuf();
of_e << "\n\n[FILE3]\n" << if_c.rdbuf();
of_e << "\n\n[FILE4]\n" << if_d.rdbuf();
```

Is there any way to know the percentage of file write with this method? If I can't, what methods do you recommend looking to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but having binary files with the `.txt` extension is quite unusual.

Comment: what percentage do you mean? You want to know what fraction of the final file is taken by the individual input files?

Comment: Workaround: you can transform the stream into string, then you would know it's size, thus you can print out that you are writing X/Y bytes currently. Second option would be to get size of the file with [file_size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size) (C++17 needed)

Comment: As for your problem there are ways to get the size of each input file, which means you can calculate percentage of each. If your compiler support the C++17 [`std::filesystem` namespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) then you can use [`file_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_size). Otherwise  Otherwise you can [seek](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) to the end and [get the current position](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/tellg).

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Yes, I'm sorry for my bad explanation.

Comment: unless you want to monitor progress while writing to the file, you could just add the sizes of the input files, use that as approximation of the output files size and get the percentages